# Two divs on the left with one on the right, no changes to HTML, CSS only

Tags: css

I'm looking to get two divs on the left and one on the right. The conundrum is that I need to accomplish this with CSS only. I cannot touch the HTML and no JavaScript.

Please view the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dale12/vb78n8Lr/) if need be.

I want the red `<div>` right up under and adjacent to the blue `<div>`.  Is this possible with only CSS?

```css
div.div1 {
   float: left;
   height: 400px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: blue;
}
div.div2 {
   clear: left;
   float: left;
   height: 15px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}    
div.div3 {
   height: 425px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div1">Div1</div>
    <div class="div3">Div3</div>
    <div class="div2">Div2</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position:relative;` on the red div and then use a negative `top` value.

```css
div.div1 {
        float: left;
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    div.div2 {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        position:relative;
        top:-25px;
    }    
    div.div3 {
        height: 425px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="div1">Div1</div>
    <div class="div3">Div3</div>
    <div class="div2">Div2</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS-grid and you can easily adjust the div like you want without changing the HTML.

Here is an example:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a c" 
  "a c"
  "a c"
  "b c";
}

div.div1 {
  grid-area: a;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.div2 {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: red;
}

div.div3 {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1">Div1</div>
  <div class="div3">Div3</div>
  <div class="div2">Div2</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a negative `margin` if you want to continue with with your approach

```
margin-top: -30px;
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vb78n8Lr/1/)